# How to identify the element for the dynamic images

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a product listing pages where i need to select the product by clicking the image and proceed to the product page.I used xpath and it was working fine, later it failed as product listed in the page keep on changing the page/place.
Need to identify any element to proceed my testing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W16b5.png)

Comment: Can you share that in plain text here

Comment: The information in the picture in insufficient. If possibly share the link to that site or at least the whole page HTML

Comment: its an internal site if i share also it will not work

Comment: looks like the sku is right there in the href... why not target that?  //a[contains(@href, "sku#_to_target")]

Comment: thnaks pcalkins its working